# JavaScript for Selecting Value of RadioButtons in MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to JavaScript so need a help please. Basically I've two radio buttons and one submit button. I want to use JS function when submit button is clicked to pick the value of radio button.

```
<td align="right" style="width: auto">
   @Html.RadioButton("SelectedOption", LinkOption.Link, true) Link Account
</td>
<td align="left" style="width: auto">
   @Html.RadioButton("SelectedOption", LinkOption.DeLink, false) De-Link Account
</td>
<td align="right" style="width:50%">
   <input type="submit" id="linkAccountSubmit" onclick="activeDeLink()" />
</td>
```

And the JavaScript function is; where I want to use the if statement to pick the value of radio buttons

```
function activeDeLink() {
    if (............) {
       $('.hiddenLink').each(function () {
           $(this).removeClass('hiddenLink');
       });
    }
    else
    {.......}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the value in this way:

```
$('input[name="SelectedOption"]').val();
```

Remember that your form will be submitted if you  not return a boolean value from the function

```
<input type="submit" id="linkAccountSubmit" onclick="return activeDeLink()" />


function activeDeLink() {
    if ($('input[name="SelectedOption"]').val() == "SomeValueToCheck") {
       $('.hiddenLink').each(function () {
           $(this).removeClass('hiddenLink');
       });

       return true;
    }
    else
    {
       // the condition is false, I dont want submit.
       return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. you've given me a good solution but still its not working. I think the problem is in val for me. I've used enum for assinging values to radiobuttons. when I use .val() == "LinkOption.DeLink" then it returns false whereas it should return true. any suggestion?

Comment: **LinkOption.DeLink** is an Enum. What is the value of LinkOption.Link in your code. In the jQuery code replace **LinkOption.DeLink** with your value .val() == "LinkOption.DeLink"